# Appinding string value in alias in yaml syntax

Tags: json, python-3.x, yaml

### How to can make variable or alias in `yaml` file and appending some more string data in a newly created alias or variable.

- #### For an example

```yaml
item: &root_directory "/home/pritam/" # This is root path of root directory of a linux systme

barsrc_file: *root_directory + ".barsrc" # Try to append some string vlaue in with root_directory.
zshrc_file: *root_directory + ".zshrc"
```

I wants to make to create a variable. With the name of **root_directory,** In which I do not have to enter the text for root_directory again, and again.

I am using yaml module of python3.11 to load the yaml file in python python as dict.

```py
import yaml

def interpolate_constructor(loader, node):
    value = loader.construct_scalar(node)
    return os.path.expandvars(value)

# Register the custom constructor
yaml.SafeLoader.add_constructor('!interpolate', interpolate_constructor)

# Load the YAML file
with open('confing.yaml') as file:
    data = yaml.safe_load(file)

# Access the values
item_value = data['item']
barcrc_file_value = data['name']['barcrc_file']

print(f"item: {item_value}")
print(f"barcrc_file: {barcrc_file_value}")
```

### Is this possible or not to append some string vlaue in alias of yaml.

#### Can json full fill my requirements for appending some string vlaue in a variable.

Answer (score 2):

YAML is not a programming language and has no variables or data transformation capabilities. There is the `!!merge` tag which is an optional extension to outdated YAML 1.1, which can merge mappings, but that's it.

You can of course write your own constructor that does this:

```py
import yaml

def concat_constructor(loader, node):
    return "".join(loader.construct_sequence(node))

yaml.SafeLoader.add_constructor('!concat', concat_constructor)

input = """
item: &root_directory "/home/pritam/"

barsrc_file: !concat [*root_directory, .barsrc]
zshrc_file: !concat [*root_directory, .zshrc]
"""
print(yaml.safe_load(input))
```

which gives

```
{'item': '/home/pritam/', 'barsrc_file': '/home/pritam/.barsrc', 'zshrc_file': '/home/pritam/.zshrc'}
```